# A value of type 'ParentData?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'StackParentData'

Tags: flutter, stack

'**final StackParentData childParentData = child.parentData;** Error occuring here'

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class CustomStack extends Stack {
CustomStack({children}) : super(children: children);

@override
CustomRenderStack createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
return CustomRenderStack(
alignment: alignment,
textDirection: textDirection ?? Directionality.of(context),
fit: fit,
//overflow: overflow,
);
}
}

class CustomRenderStack extends RenderStack {
CustomRenderStack({alignment, textDirection, fit, overflow})
: super(
alignment: alignment,
textDirection: textDirection,
fit: fit,
//overflow: overflow
);

@override
bool hitTestChildren(BoxHitTestResult result, {required Offset position}) {
var stackHit = false;

```
final children = getChildrenAsList();

for (var child in children) {
  final StackParentData childParentData = child.parentData;

  final childHit = result.addWithPaintOffset(
    offset: childParentData.offset,
    position: position,
    hitTest: (BoxHitTestResult result, Offset transformed) {
      assert(transformed == position - childParentData.offset);
      return child.hitTest(result, position: transformed);
    },
  );

  if (childHit) stackHit = true;
}

return stackHit;
```

}
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.